# How do I load an externally hosted (CDN) JS library *before* the VueJS instance is created?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, material-design-lite

I'm trying to integrate Material Design Lite in a VueJS application. I found the following blog-post:

https://posva.net/js/2015/08/26/using-material-design-lite-with-vuejs

Unfortunately, when I add this to my "main.js" file created from the `vuejs` cli tool I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef  'componentHandler' is not defined  
  /data/src/main.js:474:5
      componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.el)
```

I pushed a branch to github so the code is visible. It contains:

- [The commit introducting MDL and the error](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/commit/fbb05e0445ffafe8e4cae694103234c4d2dd22f3)
- [The "index.html" file containing the links to the CDN](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-26/frontend/powonline/index.html)
- [The VueJS "entry-point" which calls `componentHandler`](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-26/frontend/powonline/src/main.js#L474)

I'm fairly certain that MDL is loaded *after* the VueJS app is loaded, so the reference does not exist.

How can I make sure VueJS is only loaded *after* the dependencies are available?

Or, as I'm using webpack to build the code: Is there another way to integrate MDL? Maybe packing it up into the application?

Comment: Unfortunately removing "defer" did not fix the issue :( I also moved the components before calling the Vue constructor now.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kna5Gs1uYrB6TbydeaK) (if you add it back the console error matches yours) where removing defer fixes the error. I'm not sure what's different in your build.

Comment: I can see that your example manually contains the "main.js" script tag. I started from the default webpack template, and this did not contain such a line. If you look at the index.html linked in my post, you can see that there is no script tag before closing the body. Could it be related to that?

Comment: Typically webpack injects that (see the comment in your index..html) or can be configured to. I just don't think webpackbin is set up for that.

Comment: Oh. I understand. I interpreted the comment in such a way that I thought that the content of the body will be *replaced* by webpack. Note that this is the first time I use webpack and I am by no means a JS expert either. I'm still trying to wrap my head around all the involved components.

Comment: I have one last suggestion. Remove the defer, kill your dev server and whatever browser tab you are using to test this and restart the dev server.
If that doesn't do it, someone with more webpack experience will probably have to help. It does seem to be related to order of loading
I did notice though that the directive syntax is wrong for modern versions of Vue
I corrected it in the webpackbin

Comment: Unfortunately no luck :( I'll continue to play around. I've also discovered `vuetifyjs` but have other issues with it. In any case, I will keep a branch open concerning mdl, as I'm interested in this issue. I feel like there's something new to learn for me here. If someone has a suggestion, fire away, and I will give it a shot, in the hopes of finding a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

That is a linting error not an actual code error.
The *linter* couldn't find a method/variable called `componentHandler`. Doesn't necessarily mean that the code doesn't work, try using `window.componentHandler` to get the linter to stop complaining. You could also look into linter ignore rules to ignore that specific line and see if it builds then.

The linter runs in the build process in the webpack vue template, so the build will fail since it couldn't find a the reference you used in your vue codebase.
The linter doesn't know about the scripts you load externally in your html files.

As Bert said, I would also remove the `defer`

If you are unfamiliar with linters, all it does is look over your js code and check that you don't use undefined variables (like in this case), or use wrong indentation, etc. The vue template put the linter in the build process so you won't get a proper build until you have fixed everything the linter wants you to fix. You could disable linting entirely, but I recommend against it as it improves overall code quality if you keep it around imo.